# Java code dealing with arrays (Compiles but not sure if it is doing everything it is asking for)

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class UserInterface
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // for user input
        Scanner filein = new Scanner(new FileReader("products.txt")); // file of product information

        final int maxProducts = 10; // change this for maximum number of products in the catalog
        Product[] catalog = new Product[maxProducts]; // product information
        int productCount; // number of products read in from the file



        /*
         * You will need to add additional arrays and variables here.
         * The quantity array is given as an example:
         */
        int[] quantity = new int[maxProducts];
        double[] totalPrice = new double[maxProducts];
        int[] large = new int[maxProducts];
        int[] medium = new int[maxProducts];
        int[] small = new int[maxProducts];
        double[] shippingCost;
        double[] discount;

        // Read in the products from the file
        productCount = 0;
        while (filein.hasNext()) {
            catalog[productCount] = new Product();
            catalog[productCount].setName(filein.next());
            catalog[productCount].setUPC(filein.nextInt());
            catalog[productCount].setPrice(filein.nextDouble());
            catalog[productCount].setLargeCapacity(filein.nextInt());
            catalog[productCount].setMediumCapacity(filein.nextInt());
            productCount++;
        }

        // zero out all the totals and amounts to start a new order
        /* 
         * You will have to zero out all the quantity and total arrays and variables at the start
         * of each new order, or else you will end up with incorrect amounts.
         * The line below shows an easy way to fill an array with zeros, no matter how long it is:
         */
        Arrays.fill(quantity, 0);
        Arrays.fill(totalPrice, 0);
        Arrays.fill(large, 0);
        Arrays.fill(medium, 0);
        Arrays.fill(small, 0);


///////////// THIS IS LINE 56 ///////////////    

        // Ask the user to enter a quantity for each product, calculate totals and shipping boxes
        /* 
         * You will want to do this in a loop that goes through the array of products
         * (remember that the array may not be full - so you may not need to go to the end).
         * You should print out information about each product, then ask for a quantity for
         * that product, and store it in the quantity array.
         * Remember that you can call methods on the product objects even when they are in the
         * array e.g. catalog[i].getName()
         */
    for (int i = 0; i < catalog.length; i++){
          if (catalog[i] != null){
        System.out.println(catalog[i].getName());
          }
    }

        // Print the invoice line for each product ordered
        /*
         * You will want to do this in a loop that goes through the array of products.
         * Skip over products that were not ordered i.e. quantity is zero.
         */

        // Print the totals at the bottom of the invoice

        // Calculate the discounts and the final amounts, and print them

    }
}
```

Please go to the marked Line 56 in the code above. That is the question I am working on. I have my loop below that. It compiles and such but I am unsure if this is doing everything the question is asking for.

Edit: Line 56 starts like "Ask the user to enter a quantity for each product..."

Comment: What do you mean? You have a print statement in that loop: either it prints what you expect or it doesn't...

Comment: Hey @YizYaz, it is important when you ask questions like this to provide a description of what you are trying to do, what the **expected output** is, and what the **actual output** is. Without these pieces of information, it is difficult for people to provide any feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You are showing the output but you are not asking the user for the input quantity.  You will need to access System.In and read the quantity input from the user.  Also, you are still iterating the entire loop when the comment says you should not.  You are on the right track by checking for null but you should do something to end the loop once null is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of a scanner for input. it seems to me that you are only outputting the contents of the catalog array. If you want to input the amount this might help.

```
for (int i = 0; i < catalog.length; i++){
      if (catalog[i] != null){
    System.out.println(catalog[i].getName());
    System.out.print("Quantity: ");
    quantity[i] = in.nexInt();}

      }
```